# Spatial Data Migration: from Oracle to SQL Server using SSMA

Tags: sql-server, oracle, geometry, migration

I'm migrating tables and views from Oracle to SQL Server using SSMA. I have a number of tables that have columns with `SDO_GEOMETRY` datatype, SQL Server does not work with that.

How could I map `SDO_GEOMETRY` to SQL Server? If it's not possible, then what should be done using SSMA?

And is it possible to work out this issue without editing anything in the Oracle database (just using SSMA or SQL Server)?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle use an internal specific Oracle format of geo data that is non standard... Convert it to WKB or WKT and it should works.